# Do $C([0,1];\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C([0,1];\mathbb{R}^3)$ differ as measure spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

Do $C([0,1];\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C([0,1];\mathbb{R}^3)$ with the respective Borel sigma algebras under the uniform topology differ as measure spaces?

The question is simply a curiosity with no background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^3)$ are examples of Polish spaces, i.e. separable completely metrizable topological spaces. It's a general fact that for any uncountable Polish space $X$, there is a bimeasurable bijection from $X$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra to $[0,1]$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: many thanks do you have a reference?

Comment: It's called the Borel isomorphism theorem. Here are some notes I found through Google: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275b.1.14w/PDFs/Standard-Borel-Spaces.pdf